Fidelity inequality of Covariance matrix and its block diagonal version
Let $F(A,B)=\text{Trace}((A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2})$ be the fidelity between two PSD matrix $A$ and $B$. The fidelity is a quantity describing how close the two matrices are.
Given a random vector $(Y,X)\in \mathbb{R}^{1+d}$, with covariance matrix,
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{Y}^{2} & \Sigma_{1,[d]}\\
\Sigma_{[d],1} & \Sigma_{[d],[d]}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
For any $S\in [d]$, the random subvector $(Y,X_S)$ has covariance submatrix,
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_A^S = 
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{Y}^{2} & \Sigma_{1,S}\\
\Sigma_{S,1} & \Sigma_{S,S}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
If $Y$ and $X_S$ are independent, they have covariance matrix,
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_B^S = 
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{Y}^{2} & 0\\
0 & \Sigma_{S,S}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
We can then define a closeness measurement between $\Sigma_A^S$ and $\Sigma_B^S$ as $F(\Sigma_A^S, \Sigma_B^S)$.
I find the following inequality (like weak submodularity) by Python Simulation. For any $S\cap T=\emptyset$,
$$
F(\Sigma_A^{S\cup T}, \Sigma_B^{S\cup T}) \leq F(\Sigma_A^{T}, \Sigma_B^{T})+F(\Sigma_A^{S}, \Sigma_B^{S})
$$
However, I can not prove it. Could you please help me? I think it should be proved algebraically or geometrically (Because this fidelity can be converted to Bures distance, which is related to Riemann Geometry of PSD manifold).
